# Android app created for 2.1 doesn't work with 2.3

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have created an Android application that uses the 2.1 sdk as target and Min SDK Version is set to 7. The application runs fine on the emulator for both 2.1 and 2.2. And it runs fine on my phone with 2.2.1. However the app won't install when I try to run it on the emulator with Android 2.3.

What could cause this?

UPDATE:
I ran the program on another computer and it installed fine on a 2.3 AVD. So it seems to be a small problem then.

Comment: Could you post your logcat, that might provide some usefull information.

Answer (score 0):

you might have set

> < uses-sdk
>   android:maxSdkVersion="7">

, change it to 9 and it might work ...

Comment: maxSdkVersion wasn't set to anything. I tried adding it and set it to 9, but this didn't help...